# how to prevent ios app from crashing due to a 3rd party

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any possible way to prevent my ios objective c app from crashing if I install a static framework that crashes from time to time ?

The framework keeps the app in the background at all times using location.
Also, is there something that the framework's writer could have done (except for the obvious) to keep it from crashing the wrapping app ?

I'm not talking about the day to day try-catch, or the best practices (no addressing a nil object and such) - the main issue of the question is: is there a way that if any part of the framework should fault, and get an exception, that my wrapping app will have a chance to handle it ?

Comment: [Crashlytics](http://fabric.io) + [rollout.io](http://rollout.io) maybe?

Comment: This comment may not be terribly useful, but do you really need this third party app? I know if I am going to use a third-party framework it better work all the time; no reason for your users to associate that developer's bad design with your name.  That being said, you are talking about backgrounding your app; have you reviewed Apple's documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html ?

Comment: To address your specific need, this post might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691814/cllocationmanager-while-app-is-in-background-state.  I know it doesn't answer your question but it might help you roll your own solution to your specific requirement.