# Is it possible to have two different location manager authorizations?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

In my app, I have several instances, where I only need to gather the users current location while in the app. But, only one features requires background location update. I've added both permission authorization requests(along with the info.plist additions) and when the phone was plugged in to my laptop and off, the location was being updated(i used a print statement to check); however, when I unplugged it and went to test it out in the field, it didn't update my location(team member checked my location via the app on his phone). Any one know if having both causes a clash/problem?

Comment: See this thread for more information regarding this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691814/cllocationmanager-while-app-is-in-background-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have both authorisations in your project as when your app will run it will be default select "Always authorisation". As it is the universal set and will cover location updates when using the app and even if the app is in background.